# Importing not working from different folder failing but I am not receiving an error

Tags: python, import

I am working on a python program that had worked previously, but since upgrading to python 3.11, one of my imports is no longer working.

```
from Signer.engine.pdf.PyPDF2_annotate.annotations.signature import Signature
```

The statement is importing from a folder in the file structure, but no error occurs when attempting this line of code, the program quits there instead without doing the necessary function. I have traced through the code with print statements and found that the failure occurs here. I am not using an IDE, just running the code from the command line and using sublime to edit it, so there is no clear error being produced.

The file importing is called CodeSigning.py. Below is the file structure

```
CodeSignClientTool
-CodeSigning.py
-Signer
--engine
---pdf
----PyPDF2_annotate
-----annotations
------signature.py
```

Comment: The program just quits, without any error message?  That seems odd.

Comment: Try making a dummy test program that just has two lines: this import statement and `print("hello")`.  Does "hello" get printed?  If it does, then that tells us the problem is very likely not with the import, but somewhere else in your code (which you haven't shown).

Comment: Are you actually calling the code or just importing it ? Provide details.